# Get a dropdown attribute value from ProductInterface, without breaking interface contract

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, interface

I have an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface`. This product has a product attribute 'custom_attribute', which is a dropdown. Now, if this was an instance of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` I could just do: `$product->getAttributeText('custom_attribute')` to get the custom attribute text.

In the interface, `getAttributeText` is missing. So how do I get the dropdown value from `ProductInterface`, without breaking the interface contract?

I know that the interface has a method `getCustomAttribute($attributeCode)->getValue()`, but this only returns the value ID of the attribute.

Comment: A really good question